# how many abelian groups of order $8$ and $21$ exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to find how many abelian groups of order $8$ and order $21$ exist. There this theorem that states that every abelian group is a direct sum of cyclic groups. So what I did is this: $8=2\cdot2\cdot2$, now I look to all possible divisors of $8$, that is $2$, $4$ and $8$. Then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. For $G$ of order 21=7*3 we have $G$ is isomorf with $\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Thus there are $3$ abelian groups of order $8$ and $2$ abelian groups of order $21$.

My question is: is this the right way to attack this problem (if it's correct)? Thank you.

Comment: Care: $\,\Bbb Z_3\oplus\Bbb Z_7\cong\Bbb Z_{21}\,$ .

Comment: You can check your answer on [oeis](http://oeis.org/A000688). Not your argument, though.

Comment: There are two ways of classifying abelian groups of a given order. One splits the order into prime powers, and then looks at the structure for each prime power. The other looks at an element of maximum order $m$, and shows that the order of any element divides $m$ - inducting on this gives a direct product of groups of decreasing order - but the order of each later group divides the order of any earlier group. You are in danger of mixing these up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second answer needs to be modified, since the two groups you mention are isomorphic. The direct sum is cyclic of order $21$, the element $(1,1)$ is a generator.

For completeness, one should prove that the three groups of order $8$ that you list are non-isomorphic. One quick way is to observe that the first group has an element of order $8$. The other two groups do not. And the second group has an element of order $4$, while the third does not.

Comment: oke, so there is only 1 abelian group of order 21.